# I Can't find the packages that appear using grype and not found inside docker image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, grype

### This is what is inside the docker container that runs

```
docker run -it alpine:latest sh 
/ # ls -lh /var/lib/apk/
total 0
```

### when i used grype

**I use grype to run scan on the alpine docker image**

```
grype alpine:latest

NAME           INSTALLED   FIXED-IN  TYPE  VULNERABILITY   SEVERITY   
libcrypto3     3.1.4-r2    3.1.4-r5  apk   CVE-2024-0727   Medium    
libcrypto3     3.1.4-r2    3.1.4-r3  apk   CVE-2023-6129   Medium    
libcrypto3     3.1.4-r2    3.1.4-r4  apk   CVE-2023-6237   Unknown   
libssl3        3.1.4-r2    3.1.4-r5  apk   CVE-2024-0727   Medium    
libssl3        3.1.4-r2    3.1.4-r3  apk   CVE-2023-6129   Medium    
libssl3        3.1.4-r2    3.1.4-r4  apk   CVE-2023-6237   Unknown
```